C#/.Net Enforce use of specific assembly when multiple versions loaded
I need to create a class instance from a specific assembly. The assemblies (and it's dependencies) must be loadedfrom assemblies/dlls that are known runtime, not build time. So Nuget is not an option.
I can load the assemblies with it's dependencies. No problem. However one dependency also exists as another dependency of a Nuget package. However as an older version.
When I create an instance using the manually loaded assemblies, it does not use the manually loaded dependency, but the one supplied by the Nuget package. This is an older version and results in a wrong instance.
I use Net8.
The Nuget supplied assemblies reside in the application root. The manually loaded assembly resides in a separate directory.
To clarify an example:
class Child : Parent
Class Child resides in assembly A; class Parent  resides in assembly B-version2.
Another class in a referenced Nuget package references resides in assembly B-version1. These assemblies are placed in the application root.
I load assemblies A and B-version2 manually. Assembly B-version1 is loaded implicitly. Both assemblies occur in the Debug-Modules view.
When I create a Child instance using reflection, the assembly B-version1 apparently precedes over B-version2. Probably because v1 is available in the application root.
As a result the Child inhertits from the Parent in assembly version 1. This results in the Child instance missing properties that were added in version 2.
How can I create a Child using assembly B-version2 with the correct Parent?
Failed attempt:
I tried to hookup to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve events.
On load I store the manually loaded assembly. On resolve I return "my" loaded version.
As AssemblyResolve only fires when the runtime cannot resolve the assembly another way, AssemblyResolve will not be called as the runtime can resolves the assembly by simply using the (wrong) one in the application root.
Update after answer from Alberto:
I followed Alberto's suggestion:
I use a static resolver like Alberto. I load all assemblies first thing and store them in a dictionary.
I am very sure my dictionary only contains the correct assembly (Assembly B-version2 in my example).
The AssemblyResolve event only fires once for assembly A when I create an instance of Child. Not for subsequent dependent assemblies (Assembly B in the example). And as shown by a missing property on child, the runtime indeed uses the wrong assembly in the application path. Not the one I try to supply in the AssemblyResolve event, as the event does not fire.
Also I hooked on the AssemblyLoad event. It fires as soon as I access type Child and does not fire the AssemblyResolve event at that time. But in the atatched AssemblyLoad handler I can see it loads the wrong assembly from the application directory! Even when there is already another version of the assembly loaded!
So I suspect the documentation is right. AssemblyResolve only fires when thr runtime cannot resolve the correct assembly. And probing the application directory apparently occurs before firing AssemblyResolve.
Big question: is there another hook to beat the assembly resolver of the runtime to it. I could not find such a thing.

I'm curious: how can you have two different versions of the same assembly in the same directory? Usually different versions of the same assembly would have the same name.

.NET Framework or .NET Core?

@AlbertoChiesa: manually loaded assemblies come from a separate directory.

@tinmanjk: sorry. Net8. I did realise the .Net version is super relevant, but still forgot :-(

I'm not on .NET 8, so I'm not sure about the details, but I would expect AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad to allow you to return your assembly from the subdirectory. Are you returning it or only storing it somewhere for later use? I would assume you are probably not handling correctly the event. I have some code that I used to do something similar, but in .Net Framework.

Mmmm... I was checking my old code and I would like to partially retract my previous comment. It is the Assembly Resolve, not Load, that should be registered. Your comment about it not being invoked should not work that way: when you register AssemblyResolve as the first line in your program, your resolve code should run before the runtime tries to load the assembly from the standard places.

@AlbertoChiesa The documentation states that the event only fires when the runtime cannot resolve it itself:
"When you register a handler for the AssemblyResolve event, the handler is invoked whenever the runtime fails to bind to an assembly by name."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/resolve-loads
I also see your extensive answer, I will continue over there :-)

Maybe there is a fundamental misunderstanding in what you should accomplish: you cannot load different versions of the same assembly at the same time. When you receive a load request for assembly A, you should load assembly B anyway. If you are thinking that maybe your dependency would not work with version B, well, you're out of luck: you can forcefully load the most recent version (I usually do it with Newonsoft.Json), cross your fingers and hope for the best, or crash. One runtime apartment -> one version for each assemly name.

I would add: the runtime cannot resolve the assembly means "the assembly has not yet been loaded, in one version or the other". Please note that loading the latest version of an assembly could cause runtime problems and, depending upon your exact scenario, be unviable anyway.

"you cannot load different versions of the same assembly at the same time."
Still this SEEMS what happens.
First thing I "manually" load the correct version. After that he runtime implitly loads the old version. I can see that using the AssemblyLoad event.
I can actually see both  versions loaded in the "Debug-Modules" view. For me that indicates two versions were loaded.
Unless that means the second loading causes the first one to be unaccessable. The first loaded staying in memory inactively, only because assemblies cannot be unloaded. So "effectively" only one is loaded.

Unfortenately I cannot prevent the second load (AFAIK) as the AssemblyLoad event fires after the assembly already has been loaded.
I cannot overrule the load in AssemblyResolve as it won't fire at all when loading/resolving the second time.
Unless I can prevent the second load, I am afraid my adventure ends here :-(
Thanks a lot for your thinking along with me.

Wait, are you really sure that you are inded loading the Assembly v2 when AssemblyResolve triggers for v1? I would expect that, if you get to a  return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath); there is no way the runtime is later loading the Assembly v1. In other words. when the referenced library requires for v1, your loader should see that v2 is available and return that instead in AssemblyRequire.

The problem is that the AssemblyResolve does not fire at all. Neither for V1, nor V2. Apparently the runtime thinks it can do it on it's own.
AssemblyLoad does get triggered for both V1 and V2.
The first time when I load V2 with Assembly.LoadFile explitly.
But later the AssemblyLoad gets triggered for loading V1, implitly, I think as a dependency of a used nuget package.
V2 code seems not to get used anymore.

I'm not sure if this can help, but this code should work in .NET Standard 2.0 and following, so I would expect it to work also on recent versions of .NET.
However, I extensively run it only on Framework.
As you already read (I'm commenting more for others) the event you want to hookup is AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve.
This should be the very first thing you do in your Program.cs, the very first line in your main function. In fact, your main function should just register this event and then call another function doing "things". Like this (note the NoInlining):
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var qry = new TestScadaQuery();
            //var result = qry.ReadProductionSectionListByTimestamp(null, null);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += MyAssemblyResolver.AssemblyResolve;

            Start(args);
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private static void Start(string[] args)
        {
            // actually run the application
        }
    }

The resolver is a static class, like this:

public static class MyAssemblyResolver
{
    /// <summary>Index of [simple assembly name] -> file path </summary>
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> AssembliesInPath = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private static bool _shouldReload = true;

    /// <summary>Implements a AppDomain.AssemblyResolve handler, loading assemblies from a shared folder or local
    /// path, disregarding the assembly versions. </summary>
    public static Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_shouldReload) LoadAvailableAssemblies();

            // simple dll name, without extension, assumed to be equal to the dll file name.
            var simpleName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name;

            if (AssembliesInPath.TryGetValue(simpleName, out var assemblyPath))
            {
                return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
            }

            LogAssemblyNotFoundMessage(args.Name, simpleName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log exception
        }

        return null;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    private static void LoadAvailableAssemblies()
    {
        if (!_shouldReload) return;

        var currentAssemblyDirectory = GetCurrentAssemblyDirectory();
        RegisterDllsInPath(currentAssemblyDirectory, AssembliesInPath);

        var pathContainingAssemblies = "...your path";
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sharedRuntimePath)) RegisterDllsInPath(sharedRuntimePath, AssembliesInPath);

        _shouldReload = false;
    }

    private static void RegisterDllsInPath(string path, Dictionary<string, string> dlls)
    {
        var dllsInPath = new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles("*.dll", TopDirectoryOnly)
            .Where(f => f != null)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var dll in dllsInPath)
        {
            try
            {
                dlls[Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dll.Name)] = dll.FullName;
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignored
            }
        }
    }

        private static string GetCurrentAssemblyDirectory()
            => Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(MyAssemblyResolver).Assembly.Location) ??
               throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not resolve path for current assembly.");

}


I just removed some logging code using an internal framework and reversed the order of currentAssemblyDirectory and pathContainingAssemblies, but this code (at least in .Net Framework) does exactly what you're asking.
Hope it helps.

The documentation insinuates this should not work (see my comment on your other comment).
However if it actually worked for you I will investigate further.
My mechanism is quite like yours.
Now I have the Resolver as an instance class which returns types. But possibly it is not alive anymore when the type is actually created dynammically. Not sure if having hooked on event handlers is enough to keep an instance alive).
I first tried a static version. But I did not hook the events right away upon application start.
I will puzzle further and let you know.
Thank you!

I updated the question after following your suggestion.
